# Angularjs how to user ng-default with ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am having below data as input json,

```
"values":[
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.domain"},"_text":"${url}"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.port"}},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.comments"},"_text":"Defaults Comments"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.concurrent"},"_text":4}]
]
```

I am showing comments in my html page using this directive,

```
<b style="padding-top:5px;">&nbsp;Comments:</b>
<span class="input">
    <input class="inputtxt" type="text" ng-repeat="x in ValueArr" ng-if="x._attributes.name == 'data.comments'" ng-model="x._text">
</span>
```

which is working fine and showing as expected. But the problem is that sometimes, the comments node

```
{"_attributes":{"name":"data.comments"},"_text":"Defaults Comments"},
```

may not be present in array. like this,

```
"values":[
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.domain"},"_text":"${url}"},
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.port"}},        
    {"_attributes":{"name":"data.concurrent"},"_text":4}]
]
```

In that case it shows only "Comments:" and blank screen after that. It does not show input box. In this case, I want to show empty input box. I tried ng-default and and ng-init but that didn't work. How to display input box for absence of matching condition ?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e46mk349/1/)

Not getting any idea, how to achieve that. Please suggest something.

Thanks

Comment: please create a code snippet of what you tried using fiddler/codepen etc

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one.

Comment: I am sorry. Editing the question for first part only. will raise another question once first one is answered.

Comment: hi @VicJordan , created a jsfiddle "https://jsfiddle.net/e46mk349/1/"

Comment: Why not just fix the model ?

Comment: @sand check this https://jsfiddle.net/xLL46j3p/1/

Comment: @Thirueswaran , it doesn't work when the node is commented in $scope and i type something in input box. I also tried something in "https://jsfiddle.net/eyd4yL1s/"

Comment: @sand may I why are u doing and ng-repeat ? Bcos only the comment value is going to be shown and it can be accessed directly ...

Comment: @Thirueswaran Because we need to place the value against "comments" from array for matching value of "name" . Or can you show me how it can be done without ng-repeat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167717/discussion-between-thirueswaran-rajagopalan-and-sand).

Answer (score 0):

The solution works with `ng-init`.

Just put it on the `input` like this:

```
<span class="input" ng-init="initValues()">
    <input class="inputtxt" type="text" ng-repeat="x in values" ng-show="x._attributes.name == 'data.comments'" ng-model="x._text" ng-init="initInput(x)">
</span>
```

And add the function in the Controller:

```
$scope.initInputComments = function(x) {
   if (!x._text || x._text == "") {
      x._text = "Defaults Comments"
   }
}
```

Note that you need to test that `x._text` exists/is defined.

```
$scope.initValues = function() {
    var containsComment = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.values.length; ++i) {
      if ($scope.values[i]._attributes.name == 'data.comments') {
        containsComment = true;
      }
    }
    if (!containsComment) {
      $scope.values.push({
        "_attributes": {
          "name": "data.comments"
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

Check the working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e46mk349/66/)

Comment: Hi @Groben. it is not working. when i  comment/remove comment node from input , it does not show input box.

Comment: Well then I guess I don't know what you are trying to achieve. =/ If _text is not defined you want to show input with comments ?

Comment: Ok, I just unterstood, you need to update the model in your controller, before rendrering it.